# Define variable in yaml file using literal block scalar and use in kubernetes ingress file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, scalar

I have defined this below variable in yaml file using literal block scalar and want to refer them in kubernetes ingress file but it is showing |- in output.

**Variable file:**

```
domain_ingress:
    annotations: |
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-domain
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-ciphers: "HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!DH:!RSA"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

**Kubernetes Ingress file:**

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ env }}-domain-services-ingress
  annotations:
    {{ domain_ingress.annotations | to_nice_yaml }}
```

**Output is:**

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: infra2-domain-services-ingress
  annotations:
    |- <why this |- is coming in output>
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-domain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-ciphers: "HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!DH:!RSA"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Comment: Does the variable file have a trailing line break?

Comment: Please provide information how are you templating your yaml files (what tools are you using)?

Answer (score 0):

Using helm template approach I would suggest to remove from your variable file - `pipe (|)` as your `key annotations: was followed by | : Block scalar indicator`

> When a string contains line breaks, you can use the literal style, indicated by the pipe (|), to indicate that the string will span several lines.

This approach is used f.e. in ConfigMaps templates instead.

Please let me know if it helped.